# Check if variable is equal to value in specific column in MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if the value from a `<input type=" text">` is equal to ANY license key located in the database. The code below didn't work.

```
$license = $_POST['license'];    
$sql = "SELECT (licensekey) FROM wp_license";
          $sqlCheck = "SELECT (licensekey) FROM wp_license WHERE `licensekey` LIKE '%{$license}%'";
          $resultCheck = $conn->query($sqlCheck);
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          if($license == $resultCheck) {
            echo "GREAT!";
      } else {
        echo "sorry nope/";
      }
```

Comment: You don't need to compare the variable to the value in the database. Just check if the query returns any rows. If you want to check if the value is the exact same, use `licensekey = $license` instead.

Comment: remove {} in the Like to
**"SELECT (licensekey) FROM wp_license WHERE `licensekey` LIKE '%".$license."%'";**